# How do loop thru many textboxes to not allow empty values?

Tags: asp.net

I have a large quantity of textboxes for a bulk insert page textbox1, textbox, etc. How do I loop thru them to not allow empty values per when buttom is submitted?

Comment: Please share your work as it is difficult to explain.

Comment: What kind of validation are you using? Client or server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
{
   if (c is TextBox || c is RichTextBox)

        {
            ///DO SOMETHING TO AVOID IT 
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to recurse the child controls on a Page.Controls collection, too. This isn't exactly right as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
var controls = RecursiveFunctionThatRetrievesAllAppropriateControls(Page);

foreach(WebControl control in controls){
    if(control is TextBox && String.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)control).Text))
        /* ... do something ... */

    ...

}
```